# Howto increase the speed of the develpment environment

Tags: development-environment, api-platform.com

During development in the .env file the APP_ENV ist set to dev. My project has currently a couple of entity classes and APi-Platform interfaces. If I change for example one character in my User Entity the first request needs about 20 seconds until the result will be returned. during this time I can see, that in the cache/dev folder multiple files will be generated.

Is this normal, that this takes 20 seconds on a one year old mac book pro? 
Does anyone have an idea? I already disabled in php.ini xdebug.

Comment: I have faced the same problem. According to my analyses the issue lies with the docker file system which is slow on Mac. For now I don’t have a solution but it is high in my to do list. A workaround I use for now is running the build in Symfony server on the host machine itself. But on complex projects that is very inconvenient.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your info. I have already used mamp with php 7.3 on the MacBook Pro itself. Without docker. And it is very slow (15 to 20 seconds when I change an entity class). Why did you say it is inconvenient to develop on a local machine?